# Why can't I drag and drop fields in settings on a mobile phone?

Tags: field

Each field has no option to move them on a phone. Using Firefox and Chrome on a Samsung Galaxy 5.

Answer (score 4):

Touch screen devices don't "drag & drop" in a traditional sense, because dragging your finger around the screen is generally reserved for **scrolling**. This issue isn't specific to your browser or device, it's the same behavior across all touch screen devices.

Depending on how you want to look at this, I'd consider this either a "bug" or a "feature request". Assuming we're going with "feature request", your best course of action is to formally submit your request here:

> http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/

Comment: I am aware that phones dont natively allow "drag and drop" so I agree that my question is naive. Was hoping that Craft added any solution in the backend for touch devices considering that the cms is responsive. Will submit a feature.

Answer (score 1):

I have proposed a solution to this issue here:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1035

My solution is a little clunky but I think it's better than the current situation and hopefully not to hard to add.  If you think that might be helpful please go there and vote it up.